Cannot pass Mapbox secret token to expo app
I'm trying to integrate Mapbox into React Native Expo app, following the guide here. However, it will expose the Mapbox secret token, so I used dotenv to access my EXPO_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_DOWNLOAD_SECRET_TOKEN from .env.
Here's app.config.ts
import { ExpoConfig, ConfigContext } from '@expo/config';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

// initialize dotenv
dotenv.config();

const MAPBOX_SECRET_TOKEN = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_DOWNLOAD_SECRET_TOKEN;

export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => ({
  ...config,
  name: 'tamamabo',
  slug: 'tamamabo',
  version: '1.0.0',
  scheme: 'tamamabo',
  web: {
    bundler: 'metro',
    output: 'static',
    favicon: './assets/favicon.png',
  },
  plugins: [
    'expo-router',
    [
      '@rnmapbox/maps',
      {
        RNMapboxMapsVersion: '11.0.0',
        RNMapboxMapsImpl: 'mapbox',
        RNMapboxMapsDownloadToken: MAPBOX_SECRET_TOKEN,
      },
    ],
  ],
  experiments: {
    typedRoutes: true,
    tsconfigPaths: true,
  },
  orientation: 'portrait',
  icon: './assets/icon.png',
  userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
  splash: {
    image: './assets/splash.png',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  assetBundlePatterns: ['**/*'],
  ios: {
    supportsTablet: true,
  },
  android: {
    adaptiveIcon: {
      foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    package: 'com.miniemoe.tamamabo',
  },
  extra: {
    router: {
      origin: false,
    },
    eas: {
      projectId: 'd665ad8b-9fea-420f-b1b1-300f8a56a2d0',
    },
  },
});

I also add the same Mapbox secret token to expo.dev secret token manager, and access the key during runtime when building the app
Here's how I fetch the token during runtime in eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.3"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "MAPBOX_DOWNLOAD_SECRET_TOKEN": "@secret:MAPBOX_DOWNLOAD_SECRET_TOKEN"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}


I checked everything, I was able to print the content of the token in app.config.ts and expo console also says it was able to load the access token during runtime
But when I run eas build, it failed because of 401-Unauthorization (no token)
build failed
enter image description here
P.S: the mapbox doc is a mess, it literally straight up told me to expose the access token >:(
